# Adding multiple Exchange accounts under one profile in Outlook 2010 or 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013

I work for two companies, each having own Exchange Server. I want to configure my Outlook for both email accounts. I am not able to add both accounts under the same profile in Outlook 2010, nor 2013. I found some how-to articles, each involving Office Configuration Tool. However, my installation does not support this tool. I have Office 2010 Home and Business, and Office 2013 Preview click-to-run.

Is there another way?

P.S. Having two different profiles, one for each Exchange account, is inconvenient. I cannot run two instances of Outlook at the same time and switching all the time is tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Additional Exchange accounts can be added for both Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013 via the Mail applet in control panel:

[image]

Click the `E-Mail Accounts...` button, then under the E-mail tab click New:

[image]

Proceed through the wizard to add the new account. More details can be found on the [Outlook Blog](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2009/08/25/multiple-exchange-accounts-in-outlook-2010.aspx)

Comment: Yes, this is the first thing I tried. But I get a message "This profile cannot be upgraded to support additional Exchange account. Use the mail applet in the Control Panel to create a new profile." Which is what don't want.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the profile completely, and creating a new one? Maybe also try adding the accounts in the opposite order to that which you are trying now.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use mail from the control panel.  A new exchange account can be added to the current Outlook profile. 
In Outlook, on the file tab, choose INFO.
Then you can see the current account name and under that click Add Account. 
If you use this dialog to create the second account it will automatically configure the settings.  A restart of Outlook is required.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem using Outlook 2010. If a user has a pst file and it was originally created in Outlook 2002 or older file type [ANSI instead of UNICODE], you can get this message. The only way I know to fix this situation [other than have more than one profile] is to create a new empty pst file with the Outlook 2007 or newer file format. Then import the mail and other information from the old pst into it. I would archive as much as possible before doing the import. It can take hours.

There is some pretty good info here on importing and moving.
http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/convert-ansi-pst-to-unicode-pst/

Answer (score 0):

I have Outlook 2010 on Exchange 2010.

All you need to do is right click the second account in exchange and give the original account (user) full rights.

Restart the first outlook.

Done! -In Outlook, scroll way down to the bottom to see it.

If you want to be able to send as the other user, close outlook and head to "control panel" then "mail32". Add the second account.

Now at the top of the a message you can change the sender.

If choose to have both inboxes in "Favorites" (for easy access at the top) the accounts will be labeled so you tell them apart (same is true for "sent" folder etc.).

Comment: The user wants a second account on a second Exchange server not a second account on the same server.  Basically adding a new mail service

Answer (score 0):

This is overkill, and maybe not quite as convenient as you want, but:

Run one instance of Outlook on your physical machine, and another one
(or another Exchange-compatible mail client) on a virtual machine. 
You might not get notifications on your main desktop of new mail from the VM,
but switching to it to check that account
should be much quicker than switching profiles in Outlook.